# Using :attr_accessible with role-based authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, security-roles

In my online store, users are allowed to change certain properties of their orders (e.g., their billing address), but not others (e.g., the origination ip address). Administrators, on the other hand, are allowed to modify *all* order properties.

Given, this, how can I use `:attr_accessible` to properly secure my Order model? Or will I have to use it to mark accessible all attributes that administrators can modify and refrain from using `Order.update_attributes(params[:order])` in those controller actions that ordinary users can access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, attr_accessible is not the tool you're looking for and Rails doesn't come with anything built in that does what you want.

If you want fine-grained control over who can update specific attributes in a model, you could do something like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_attributes_as_user(values, user)
    values.each do |attribute, value|
      # Update the attribute if the user is allowed to
      @order.send("#{attribute}=", value) if user.can_modify?(attribute)
    end
    save
  end
end
```

Then you can change your `Order.update_attributes(params[:order])` to `Order.update_attributes_as_user(params[:order], current_user)` and assuming you implement the `User#can_modify?` method to return true in the correct cases, it should work.

Comment: In Rails 3.1, the :as => :role option has been added wherever you can assign attributes. So this has now been built in. http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activemodel/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security_rb.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and now I'm using this gem http://github.com/dmitry/attr_accessible_block

It's easy and used in some production website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to modify the actions, so permissions are checked inside the actions. Calling `Order#update_attributes` will not work for the general user.

I can't rember a role-based authorization plugin that would allow something you are looking for. This is because these plugins mixin to the controllers and not the models. They would also need to mixin into `ActiveRecord::Base` to check for `attr_accesible` etc.